# ConflictException thrown not being catched by ConflictExceptionMapper

Tags: java, jersey

I'm new to jersey, and I want to throw a ConflictException(Custom) in my Service,
and catch it to give a response.

Below is my code..

```
public class ConflictException extends ClientErrorException {
    public ConflictException() {
        super(Response.Status.CONFLICT); // 409
    }
}
```

Then I want to use a ExceptionMapper to send a proper Response.

```
@Provider
public class ConflictExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<ConflictException> {
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(ConflictException exception) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.CONFLICT).entity(new ResponseMessage( Collections.emptyList(), OperationResultStatus.Conflict,
                exception.getMessage())).build();
    }
}
```

Somehow this Mapper is not being triggered.

What am I doing wrong....

Update!!! Snipped of my main class included.

```
final ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig().packages(packages)
                // Now you can expect validation errors to be sent to the client.
                .property(ServerProperties.BV_SEND_ERROR_IN_RESPONSE, true)
                // @ValidateOnExecution annotations on subclasses won't cause errors.
                .property(ServerProperties.BV_DISABLE_VALIDATE_ON_EXECUTABLE_OVERRIDE_CHECK, true)
                // Further configuration of ResourceConfig.
                //.property(ServerProperties.PROCESSING_RESPONSE_ERRORS_ENABLED, true)
                .register(new ClassBinder())
                .register(json)
                .register(ConstraintViolationExceptionMapper.class)
                .register(ConflictExceptionMapper.class);
```

Comment: How are you registering it?

Comment: I'm registering it in my main class. I Will update my post with the main class.